# How to optimize internet speed?

Tags: wifi, internet, asus

I installed elementary OS Freya 64bit dual boot with Windows 7 on an ASUS Z54C laptop.
I have an extremely slow Wifi connection on elementary OS but when I boot on Windows 7 it's really fast. How do I get my wifi working? When I go to Google.com it takes like 2 minutes to load.

Edit: The internet was so slow that I uninstalled elementary OS

Update: May 12th 2016
Installed Freya on my old computer

Answer (score 1):

RESET THE MODEM & ROUTER (it worked)

If that didn't work for you
Go to 
System Settings >
Network >
Options >
IPv6 Settings >
Method > 
Change from Automatic to ignore >
Save

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this working for me:

1. First go Network -> Options -> IPv4
2. Second add dns I am using this dns: https://1.1.1.1/

My dns address: (1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1)